# setTimeout confusion

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I have an array `words` and it has words in it. I want to display say 'N' number of words per second. I wrote the code below and it is working for the first instance only. Please let me know.

```
tempstr = "";
for(k=0;k<grupof;k++)
    tempstr += words[k] + " ";
i =  grupof;
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    (function insertArray(){
         $("p").text(tempstr); 
         if(i <words.length){
              setTimeout(insertArray, 2000);
              tempstr = "";
              for(j=i;j<grupof;j++)
                  tempstr += words[j] + " ";
              i = j;
         }
    })();
});
```

Here is the jsfiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Skg7d/2/

Comment: What do you mean with *"it is working for the first instance only"*? Please create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo.

Comment: The fiddle fails on undefined variable `grupof`.  :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(j=i;j<grupof;j++)
```

needs to be

```
for(var j=i;j<grupof + i;j++)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using `setInterval` instead.  Here's a working example:

```
var strn = "It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).";

var wordsPer = 2;
var duration = 500;

function showWords(words) {
    for (var i = 0; i < wordsPer; i++) {
        if (words.length > 0) {
            el.innerHTML += ' '+ words.shift();
        }
    }
    if (words.length == 0) {
        clearInterval(intervalID);
    }
}

var words = strn.split(" ");
var el = $("p")[0];
var intervalID = setInterval(function() {
    showWords(words);
}, duration);
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Skg7d/3/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var words = new Array("word1", "word2", "word3", "word4", "word5", "word6", "word7"); 

$(document).ready(function(){

    function insertArray(group, index){
        var tempstr = "";

        if(group+index > words.length){
             if(words.length - index <= 0)
                 return;
             else
                 group = words.length - index;
        }

        for(var k=0;k<group;k++)
            tempstr += words[k + index] + " ";

         index += group;             
         $("p").text(tempstr); 
         if(index < words.length)
             setTimeout(function(){insertArray(group, index);}, 2000);
    }
    insertArray(2,0);

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/reesewill/8ZTYx/

Comment: No explanation of what you changed and why?

Comment: Your main issue is your last for loop. The index isn't being reset so it will never go past the first group. I have handled that in my modified function. Also, I've added a catch to display a partial group for the last iteration of timer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Skg7d/19/

```
var strn = "It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).";

var wordsPerInterval = 3,
    duration = 500,
    el = $('p'),
    words = strn.split(' ');

el.html('');

var interval = setInterval(function() {
    var toInsert = words.slice(0, wordsPerInterval);

    words = words.slice(wordsPerInterval, words.length);

    if (toInsert.length)
        el.html(el.html() + toInsert.join(' ') + ' ');
    else
        clearInterval(interval);
}, duration);
```